# Admin firebase Error - "Error: Requested entity was not found." when trying to send remote notification

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I'm use node js server for sending remote notification with ""firebase-admin" package

```
  await admin
  .messaging()
  .send(dataMessage)
  .then(console.log("Data sent"))
  .catch((err) => console.log("Error" + err));


  export const dataMessage = (fcmToken, messageData) => {
  const apns = {payload: {aps: {"content-available": true}}};
  const message = {
    token: fcmToken,
    data: messageData,
    apns
  };
  return message;
};
```

I don't know why but randomly i get "Error: Requested entity was not found." and i can't realize why.
Any advise will be great because it's really frustrating

Comment: If it happens sporadically it may have something to do with the device registration tokens. I'd recommend logging the errors, along with the tokens that caused them and then contacting Firebase support with that information for further guidance.